# How to FIND and READ data from WorkItemInfo, SessionInfo Tables

Tags: jbpm

I am using persistence for executing the processes including Asynchronous workitems. I need to access to the contents of the persistence tables (WorkItemInfo) in order to get run-time information.

But I can not find the table and don't know how to read data from them??

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a WorkItemInfo table in the database you configured.  Note that most examples use an H2 in memory database by default, you can use the h2 console to take a look.

Note that access to the XXXInfo tables directly is in general not recommended.  You might consider having your handler store the necessary information in some table yourself and querying that (similar to how the task service stores task data in the task tables).

Alternatively, it might be easier though to use a ksession to get the information you need, using:
((org.drools.core.process.instance.WorkItemManager) ksession.getWorkItemManager()).getWorkItem(id);